# Import TXT file Into MySQL table every 5 seconds

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = 'root';

$database = 'test';
$table = 'test';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");


    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
         $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
         echo 'upload file name: '.$fname.' ';
         $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

         if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "txt")
         {

             $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
             $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

             while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {
                $sql = "INSERT into graph(note,per,cpu,perc) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]')";
                mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
             }

             fclose($handle);
             echo "Successfully Imported";

         }
         else
         {
             echo "Invalid File";
         }   
    }

    ?>
    <h1>Import txt file</h1>
    <form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Import File : <input type='file' name='sel_file' size='20'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>
```

This is my code for import txt file into MySQL table.

But I want to this code automatically import txt file to mysql every 5 seconds. 
It mean I will setup url of txt file and every 5 seconds , it will import to mysql.
Please help me and sorry my English . thanks all

Comment: You need to set up "Cron Job"

Comment: You maybe want to use the function `readfile` to load a file from the filesystem and react to it (like importing its data to your database).

Comment: You should also stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and start escaping your inputs (or use prepared statements with mysqli or pdo).

Comment: can you say more details . thanks

Comment: Use PDO instead of mysql_* functions! and yes cron job will work for you!

Comment: What is your exact requirement? To import a set of csv files or import a single file over and over again with 5 sec interval?

Comment: @BlackMamba07 import a single file over and over again with 5 sec.Can You help me fix this code

Answer (score 0):

If you need to import a file every 5 seconds from a list of files that is growing, then you should set up a [cron](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) job for that. Or if you want to import, say just 50(small) files or so, then you can put your code inside a recursive function with a sleep time of 5 seconds and execute it via shell. Also do use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension as the MySQL(Original) extension is deprecated.

Comment: I need to import a file every 5 seconds. Only 1 file
thanks you for support.